# Imprimir resultados en un Array

Tags: javascript, array, bucle-for, bucles

soy un principiante autodidacta de JS y estoy recién comenzando con problemas muy simples. En uno de esos problemas me encuentro con que doy con el resultado solicitado, pero me piden que lo imprima en un array y eso eso lo que no sé hacer. El problema es el siguiente:

"Estás trabajando en un programa de gestión de tiendas, que almacena los precios en un arreglo
Necesitas añadir una funcionalidad para aumentar los precios en la cantidad dada. La variante increase es tomada de la entrada del usuario. Es necesario aumentar todos los precios del arreglo dadoen esa cantidad y entregar a la consola el arreglo resultante."

y este es el código que tengo.
Lo que necesito es guardar lo que me arroja total en un array.
Espero que puedan ayudarme. Mil gracias.

```js
function main() {
    var num = prompt()
    var increase = parseInt(num, 10);
    var prices = [98.99, 15.2, 20, 1026];
    //your code goes here
    for (var i = 0; i< prices.length; i++) {
    var total = prices[i] + increase; 
        console.log(total)
    }
}
main()
```

Comment: Hola @NeaCS, estamos en una comunidad de habla hispana, y los comentarios o textos en inglés pueden resultar ininteligibles para muchos, te recomiendo que traduzcas el texto de tu pregunta al castellano. Un saludo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Una opción facil y sencilla es modificar directamente tu array de `prices`

```js
function main() {
    var num = prompt()
    var increase = parseInt(num, 10);
    var prices = [98.99, 15.2, 20, 1026];
    //your code goes here
    for (var i = 0; i< prices.length; i++) {
      prices[i] += increase; 
    }
    console.log(prices)
}
main()
```

En caso quieras conservar el array `prices`, solo debemos de crear un array vacío y luego ir agregando el nuevo dato con el método `push`.

```js
function main() {
    var num = prompt()
    var increase = parseInt(num, 10);
    var prices = [98.99, 15.2, 20, 1026];
    //your code goes here
    let resultados = [];
    for (var i = 0; i< prices.length; i++) {
      resultados.push(prices[i] +increase); 
    }
    console.log(resultados)
}
main()
```

Comment: Graciasss! Estoy impresionada con la rapidez y calidad de las respuesta.

Comment: todo eso depende de la calidad de tu pregunta :D